# XCode 9.4.1 breakpoint doesn't hit when release build scheme

Tags: xcode, release, breakpoints

I'm using XCode 9.4.1.
I need to hide print log when release mode, so I add #if-#endif conditions and want to check if these working correctly.
So I change my build scheme to release but breakpoint not wroking.

I found some answers on StackOverflow, and try any method that I can, but That's not working either.

Is there something else that I can try more?

[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way print logs never work in Release build so why do you want to add this condition ?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh The reason is not important. Becuase, it just sort of trigger of my curious. The point of this answer is that I just want to enable breakpoint and step-by-step debugging in Release scheme. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your build Setting set optimization level none for release.

[image: Set optimization level no for release]

Set Build Active Arch to Yes for release.

[image]

Set Debug information format to DWARF for release

[image]